# When I do follow path, the object is not followed with SHP-Root

Tags: rigging

[image]

When I do Car rigging and try to do follow path like this picture, the object is not followed with SHP-Root. just only SHP-Root is on path. I'm using blender 2.92 file and Rigacar v6.0 add-on. should I change my version of blender?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see in your screenshot, all location, rotation and scale channels of your SHP-Root are locked. Unlock them clicking on their lock icon on the "N" properties panel.

Changing version of Blender doesn't matter at all.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, Thanks to you, I can solve my problem!